# Moving a file between features in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am deploying a file using a sharepoint feature and the module element.  I now need to move this module to another feature but it seems that when I do this sharepoint errors as it has less an entry in the alldocs table.  This entry has a leafname refering to the old feature.  Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to de-activate the previous feature in order to do this.  This will un-provision the earlier module elements and allow you to re-provision with the new feature by activating it.